# How can i add style to the root of React's CreatableSelect?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

in the 'React select' docs (https://react-select.com/styles#style-object) it says that you can change the styles of the select container, but I can't find how to change the `root` element style.

can it be done? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the `root` element has no styles (expect `position: relative; box-sizing: border-box;`) so I'm not sure what styles you want to change but you can set its styles by targeting its `className`.

e.g

```
<Select
  className="container"
/>
```

```css
.container {
  background: red;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-hawking-2prwd?file=/example.js

A bit explanation: *react-select* doesn't offer a prop for the root element because there is no need to. The whole reason of the `styles` prop is because the inner classes are scoped ([For example](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)). This is not the case of the root element.

Comment: I was looking for a props answer and not a CSS one. but maybe there isn't one. thanks anyways

Comment: Why you prefer props approach? You need props approach only because you can't get the inner elements classes (because they scoped). You **don't need** styles props when you target the root element. That's why react-select are not giving this option. (In other words, it's not a bug. It's by design).

Comment: I love CSS don't get me wrong but the way we make components at my work is very inline-style/props/dynamic oriented. not everybody on the team will know how to work in the CSS files and probably will wrap the component with another `root` like div. which I don't like to see happen. but it's ok, will make things work. thanks!